# Assign entries to categories in bulk?

Tags: categories, admin

I just accidentally dragged a root category onto another. Now, all of the entries that were assigned to that category are assigned to the one I accidentally dragged it onto.

Luckily, I have like 7 entries but if this happened with a lot of them I'd be pretty screwed. It seems like a disaster waiting to happen.

Is there an easy way to "bulk assign" categories? If that's not possible is there anyway to add a "Save" button to the category manager so I'd have to click save before the database actually updates? Am I overlooking something really, really obvious here? Definitely wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, right now, the only way to deal with that is at the DB level. I believe you would only have to deal with the `craft_relations` table for adding / removing categories to entries.

Comment: Looking through the sql dump this doesn't seem too bad! I'd love to see something more elegant. I'll wait a bit and see if anything pops up before I accept.

Comment: You could build a plugin to do it but I think that, in the use case you describe, SQL queries would be the easiest

Comment: Agreed. My issue is definitely taken care of. I'm also trying to think about it for the long run, though. I have no problem editing a SQL dump but a client would poop their pants!

Comment: It is now nearly 8 years since this question was asked, and I ended up here because I have the same question. Is this _still_ not possible to do somehow? I mean, it feels almost a bit rudimentary to be perfectly honest.